# Nginx not receiving second request after 100-Contnue, 401 response

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-location, nginx-config

For the below configuration, the request 2 is not reflecting in nginx. There is no error log, and nothing in access log for request 2.

The issue started occurring only after 100-Continue, 401 Unauthorized was introduced as initial response. If request 1 is responded with 101 from proxied server, everything (the end websocket connection is established).

Expected behavior:
Second request should successfully reach proxy and then to proxied server. After that it will be coverted to websocket connection.

Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin.example.com;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/key.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    server_name_in_redirect on;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location /my_line/ {
        proxy_pass        https://y.y.y.y/;
        proxy_set_header  Host y.y.y.y;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Origin '';
        keepalive_timeout 100s;
        proxy_set_header Expect $http_expect;
        proxy_read_timeout 7200;
    }

    error_page  404              /index.html;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"  always;
    }
}
```

REQUEST 1:

```
GET /myserver/my_line/84620 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Authorization: Basic ODQ2MjA6c3MxOE1VRUs5UEF6RTB5eHoyVmpSZ0Roc3VyV0tCcA==
User-Agent: MyApp/WebSocketClient/
Host: x.x.x.x
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: DhaIyjupEbTHXQvX3asVeA==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: Web_Proxy
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: mux
Expect: 100-continue
```

response 1

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 16:33:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

response 2

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 16:33:51 GMT
Expires: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 16:34:51 GMT
Cache-Control: private,max-age=60
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebSocket Group@myapp", domain="", nonce="f9beaf5521a1cdf078362b68a4332df5", algorithm=MD5
Server: MyServer/
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 0
```

REQUEST 2

```
GET /myserver/my_line/84620 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
Authorization: Digest username="84620", realm="WebSocket Group@myapp", nonce="f9beaf5521a1cdf078362b68a4332df5", uri="/myserver/my_line/84620", response="5d8bb7c396724bb840da698c06f19629", algorithm=MD5, nc=00000056
User-Agent: MyApp/WebSocketClient/
Host: x.x.x.x
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: DhaIyjupEbTHXQvX3asVeA==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: Web_Proxy
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: mux
```

Issue -> The second request is not reflected in the nginx access logs, There is nothing in error logs.

The nginx is supported to proxy the request to the proxied server and not do anything else own it's own. The TCP connection between client and proxy, proxy and proxied server was intact when REQUEST2 was triggered from client. I suspect the configuration at nginx has issue wrt the Connection and Upgrade headers. 
I have captured all wireshark at nginx and it clearly states that the tcp connection was in place and request 2 was ack by nginx. It is just that nginx is not processing it - as if it goes in blackhole and doesn't come out from it.

Request your expert help. Thanks.

Comment: Point to be noted here is there is a difference in the way websocket proxy is used - https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/. Here there are multiple HTTP requests flowing on the same tcp connection and then it is supposed to be upgraded to ws.

Comment: Why there is different authorization header and user agent in request 2, can you explain why?

Comment: It was a typo of sorts for user agent. I corrected it and they have same value. As for Authorization header, the values are entirely passed on to proxied server and it is the response challenge mechanism devised between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your Request 1, there is no body but you are getting a 100 continue response from the proxied server, which I believe is due to Expect request-header "100-continue" added by Nginx (probably due to the config entry proxy_set_header Expect $http_expect;), but this is wrong as per the spec,

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

A client MUST NOT send an Expect request-header field (section 14.20) with the "100-continue" expectation if it does not intend to send a request body.

This might be the reason for the hang, as the server might be waiting for a body (for Request 1) that is never going to arrive.

Comment: The client in REQUEST 1 is passing Expect: 100-continue and hence proxied server (and also nginx) sending the 100  Continue response as expected. Issue is in step 3 where the request hits nginx and further relayed to proxied server, the underlying TCP connection is a new one and not same as the created in the first go of request 1.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, the second request is received by the proxy Nginx and is forwarded to the proxied Nginx on a separate TCP connection, but you dont see the second request in the proxied Nginx's logs, right?

Comment: Yes, the second request is received by nginx proxy but no further clue as to what happened to it. As per wireshark traces, ACK was sent to requesting client. The TCP connection with the proxied server was terminated by nginx. So it looks that nginx gobbled the Request 2 with no traces anywhere.